# Python - Read 3 line in a textfile at the same time

Tags: python

i have a `file.txt` that look like this.

```
testings 1
response 1-a
time 32s

testings 2
response 2-a
time 32s

testings 3
*blank*

testings 4
error

testings 5
response 5-a
time 26s
```

and prints

```
['testings 1', 'testings 2', 'testings 3', 'testings 4', 'testings 5']     
['response 1-a', 'response 2-a', 'response 5-a']
['time 32s', 'time 20s', 'time 26s']
```

So it´s a simpel code i have, it opens the file, uses `readlines()` and looks for the keywords `testings` ,`response` and `time` then appends the string to 3 seperat lists. As shown in the `file.txt` some `testings x` are either `*blank*` or has an `error` instead off a `response`. My problem is that i need the lists to always have the same lenght. Like this:

```
 ['testings 1', 'testings 2', 'testings 3', 'testings 4', 'testings 5']
 ['response 1-a', 'response 2-a', '*error*', '*error*', 'response 5-a']
 ['time 32s', 'time 20s', '*error*', '*error*',  'time 26s']
```

So i was thinking if it´s posbile to "read for 3 lines at the same time" and have a if-statment where all the 3 lines need to have the right keywords ("be True") or else insert `*error*` in the response and time list to keep the lenght right. Or is there even a better way to keep 3 list at the same lenght?

```
test = []
response = []
time =[]

with open("textfile.txt",'r') as txt_file:
    for line in txt_file.readlines():
        if ("testings") in line:
            test.append(line.strip())    
        if ("response") in line:
            response.append(line.strip())
        if ("time") in line:
            time.append(line.strip())


print (response)
print (test)
print (time)
```

Comment: Don't use `.readlines()`; just iterate over the file *directly*. There is no need to read the whole thing into memory here, `for line in text_file` works just fine.

Comment: @sesar `*blank*` is a value or empty string?(`file.txt`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet does what you are seeking. You can use `next(txt_file, '')` to retrieve the next line without having to load the file into memory first. Then, you look only for lines that contain "testing", and when you do, you compare the next two lines. it will always add one string to each list, any time it finds "testing", however, if it doesn't find "response" or "time" then it will insert errors where appropriate. Here is the code, using the input you gave above.

```
with open("textfile.txt", "r") as txt_file:
     test = []
     response = []
     time = []
     for line in txt_file:
         if "testings" in line:
             test_line = line.strip()
             response_line = next(txt_file, '').strip()
             time_line = next(txt_file, '').strip()
             test.append(test_line)
             if "response" in response_line:
                 response.append(response_line)
             else:
                 response.append("*error*")
             if "time" in time_line:
                 time.append(time_line)
             else:
                 time.append("*error*")
```

And the Output:

```
In : test
Out: ['testings 1', 'testings 2', 'testings 3', 'testings 4', 'testings 5']

In : response
Out: ['response 1-a', 'response 2-a', '*error*', '*error*', 'response 5-a']

In : time
Out: ['time 32s', 'time 32s', '*error*', '*error*', 'time 26']

In : len(test), len(response), len(time)
Out: (5, 5, 5)
```

Comment: thanks! I made some changes but no change that would compromise the function and i changed file to my real file thats much much longer. But now i have a problem where i get this msg "list index out of range" and its only because of this line `txt_lines[i+2].strip()` i put in 2 there and the list gose out of range. Is there a way to get around that problem?

Comment: Sorry about that! I actually uploaded the first version of the code snippet I wrote here. It used `readlines()` and indexing instead of `next()`, which is more robust, and also doesn't load the entire file into memory up front. should be faster and more memory efficient! It should also handle the end of file issue; if there are missing lines at the end of the file, it should default to "\*error\*" for `response` and `time`

Answer (score 2):

Text file are [iterables](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator), meaning you can loop over them directly, or you can use the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to get another line from them. The file object will always produce the next line in the file whatever method you are using, even when mixing techniques.

You can use this to pull in more lines in a `for` loop:

```
with open("textfile.txt",'r') as txt_file:
    for line in txt_file:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('testings'):
            # expect two more lines, response and time
            response_line = next(txt_file, '')
            if not response_line.startswith('response'):
                # not a valid block, scan forward to the next testings
                continue
            time_line = next(txt_file, '')
            if not time_line.startswith('time'):
                # not a valid block, scan forward to the next testings
                continue
            # valid block, we got our three elements
            test.append(line) 
            response.append(response_line.strip())
            time.append(time_line.strip())
```

So when a line starting with `testings` is found, the code pulls in the next line. If that line starts with `response`, another line is pulled in. If that line starts with `time`, then all three lines are appended to your data structures. If neither of those two conditions are met, the the outer `for` loop is continued and reading the file continues until another `testings` line is found.

The added bonus is that the file is never read into memory in one go. File buffering keeps this efficient, but otherwise you never need more memory than is needed for the final set of lists (valid data), and the three lines currently being tested.

Side note: I'd *strongly* recommend you do not use three separate lists of equal length. You could just use a *single* list with tuples:

```
test_data = []
# ... in the loop ...
test_data.append((line, response_line.strip(), time_line.strip()))
```

and then use that single list to keep each triplet of information together. You can even use a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple

TestEntry = namedtuple('TestEntry', 'test response time')

# ... in the loop
test_data.append(TestEntry(line, response_line.strip(), time_line.strip()))
```

at which point each entry in the `test_data` list is an object with `test`, `response` and `time` attributes:

```
for entry in test_data:
    print(entry.test, entry.response, entry.time)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

with open("textfile.txt",'r') as txt_file:
    for batch in grouper(txt.readlines, 3):
        if ("testings") in batch[0]:
            test.append(line.strip())
        else:
            test.append('error')
        if ("response") in batch[1]:
            response.append(line.strip())
        else:
            response.append('error')
        if ("time") in batch[2]:
            time.append(line.strip())
        else:
            time.append('error')
```

This assumes there will always be the lines in the same order, and that the file is always organised in batches of three lines, even if that is just a blank line. Since it actually looks like your input file has a blank line between each group of 3 you may need to change grouper to read batches of 4.